Calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln (\sin^2 x)}{1+x^2} dx$
I found this thing in the "Table of Integrals, Series and Products" p. 569
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln (\sin^2 x)}{1+x^2} dx = 2 \pi \ln \left( \frac{1-e^{-2}}{2}\right)$$

My first attempt.
I noticed that the integrand has discontinuities at pi-fold points, so I assumed that it makes sense to try the Lobachevsky formula or something like it. I tried to take an idea from it and this is what I got:
$$
I=\sum_{n\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}} \int_{\pi n}^{\pi n + \pi} \frac{\ln (\sin^2 x)}{1+x^2} dx = |x=t+\pi n|= \sum_{n\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\ln (\sin^2 t)}{1+(t+\pi n)^2} dt = 
$$
$$
=\int_{0}^{\pi} dt \ln (\sin^2 t) \sum_{n\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{1+(t+\pi n)^2}
$$
The sum of the series is calculated using the properties of complex numbers and the digamma function.
$$
\sum_{n\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{1+(t+\pi n)^2}= \frac{\left(\cos2t+\cosh2\right)\sinh2}{\sin^{2}2t+\sinh^{2}2}
$$
Replacing the series with this monster we get a horrible looking integral:
$$
I= \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln (\sin^2 t) \frac{\left(\cos2t+\cosh2\right)\sinh2}{\sin^{2}2t+\sinh^{2}2} dt
$$
I have no idea what i should do with it.

My second attempt.
After a few unsuccessful substitutions, I assumed that a complex analysis can help me.
I constructed a contour with notches at all special points except i. But I've discovered one unpleasant thing: Domain coloring of the function
The problem is that the function goes to another sheet, which makes it impossible to just take a half-circle contour. I tried combining both ways: I split the integral into a sum and tried calculating the pieces separately using residues, but it's worse there.
How to calculate it?

Have you considered the substitution $t=\tan x$?

The discontinuities are at the points $\frac{\pi}{2} n$

sorry I mixed up the functions because I was looking at them almost at the same time

Have you considered using Laplace transforms?

@MathGuy substitutions does not give a normal result, Laplace transform gives a divergent integral

Note that the integrand is an even function. Therefore:
$$
2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln(\sin^2 x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx.
$$
Recall the Fourier series expansion for $\ln(\sin x)$ on the interval $(0, \pi)$:
$$
\ln(\sin x) = -\ln 2 - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2k x)}{k}.
$$
Hence:
$$
\ln(\sin^2 x) = -2\ln 2 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2k x)}{k}.
$$
Substituting the expansion into the integral:
$$
2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{-2\ln 2 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2k x)}{k}}{1 + x^2} \, dx, 
$$
which simplifies to:
$$
-4 \ln 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} - 4 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(2k x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx.
$$
The first integral is:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
Using the standard integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(a x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-a},
$$
for $a > 0$, and then, for $a = 2k$:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(2k x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-2k}.
$$
Substituting these results back:
$$
-4 \ln 2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} - 4 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-2k} = -2\pi \ln 2 - 2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2k}}{k}.
$$
Recognizing the series as a logarithmic function:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2k}}{k} = -\ln(1 - e^{-2}), 
$$
the integral becomes:
$$
-2\pi \ln 2 + 2\pi \ln(1 - e^{-2}) = 2\pi \ln \left(\frac{1 - e^{-2}}{2} \right).
$$

Oh, I forgot about the Fourier series. Thank you!
